# Prevent abbrev expansion on capitalization

Tags: abbrev

Is there a way to get abbrev expansion on a lower case abbrev but not on its upper case version?

E.g.: I have "r" expanding to "are". I'd like "R" to stay "R".

I don't necessarily want to get rid of capitalization completely, so I'd still like "Btw" to expand to "By the way", but if there is no other option I'd take it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: just put a non-nil value for the `:case-fixed` property.

```
(define-abbrev my-foo-abbrev-table "r" "EmacsRocks" nil
               :case-fixed t)
```

See `C-h v define-abbrev RET` for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Even better, you can do it also in `define-abbrev-table`. The property has to go *before* the counter value. E.g.:  `("r" "are" nil :case-fixed t 332)`

Comment: Yes, it can be applied to the whole abbrev table, if you prefer.  As for the position of the counter: not really! the counter value is just another property, so it should be `("r" "are" nil :case-fixed t :counter 332)` but the ordering of the properties doesn't matter.