unexplained abbreviation expansion
I have an abbreviation that expands into an org mode link -- for example, it changes gmdn into [[abbrev:Global Medical Device Nomenclature][GMDN]], and I have org configured to color the resulting link green. I can then hover or move point over the link, and see the expansion for "GMDN".
(The idea is that it's not an actual link to some location, just a convenient way of, well, abbreviating something.)
Somehow, though, for one of my abbrevs, emacs will also expand "GMDN" -- but it expands that into [[Abbrev:Global Meical Device Nomenclature][GMDN]]. Note the capital A on "Abbrev". I just want the lowercase "abbrev".
I can't find anywhere where this behavior is configured. I've restarted emacs, and it persists. I can't find anything that would cause this -- but something automatically changes "GMDN" into the above org link when I type it.
How can I find that something? I want to debug something, or similar, but I don't see anything.
list-abbrevs doesn't have anything, and I tried debugging abbrev--default-expand. That turned GMDN into...gmdn! But then the result in my buffer is the link. I don't know where the "Abbrev" expansion is happening.
Ideas?

Oooh, this might be related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62557/abbrev-capitalizes-first-character?rq=1

Yeah, that's the one I found, and the :case-fixed t solution there works for me -- although I still would like to have the mixed-case abbreviation expand the same way the all-lowercase one does. But that's good enough for now.
